# Send raw transaction using web3 0.20.0 and Infura

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, web3js

I want to sent a raw transaction using web3 0.20.0 and infura. This is my RawTransaction object:

```
var data = instance.MyMethod(‘123');

var rawTransaction = {
    "from": myAddress,
    "nonce": web3js.toHex(count),
    "gasPrice": web3js.toHex(gasPrice),
    "gasLimit": web3js.toHex(gasLimit),
    "to": ‘contractAddress,
    "value": "0x1",
    "data": data,
    "chainId": 0x03
};
```

I have problem with the “data” that should be written on the contract…

All the examples on the net that use web3 1.0 version look like this:

```
var data = instance.MyMethod(‘123’).encodeABI();

var rawTransaction = {
    "from": myAddress,
    "nonce": web3js.toHex(count),
    "gasPrice": web3js.toHex(gasPrice),
    "gasLimit": web3js.toHex(gasLimit),
    "to": contractAddress’,
    "value": "0x1",
    "data": data,
    "chainId": 0x03
};
```

The function encodeABI() doesn’t exist in web3 0.20.0 …

So please help me how to send a raw transaction with web3 0.20.0.

Tnx!

Comment: `getData()` is the 0.20.x version of `encodeABI()`.

Comment: Thank you @smarx!